# Is anybody using 13F-HR data for making strategies?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies

I see that a lot of quants work on high frequency strategies. Mostly used data are prices, volumes. 
I wonder, is anybody using data on funds positions, which they have to disclosure quarterly under Securities Exchange Act? I mean 13F-HR and 13F-HR/A forms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are plenty of people looking at 13F information.

There are even [ETF's with strategies](http://alphaclonefunds.com/) following 13F information for top funds.

There are also [websites](http://whalewisdom.com/) that parse and display this information as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is some interesting work that can be done by looking at the predictive value of filings. Fintel is doing some work around this - you can see a sample of Baker Brothers performance https://fintel.io/i/baker-bros-advisors-lp - for more information, see also https://fintel.io/b/2017-8-24-determining-investor-sentiment-in-industries-by-examining-institutional-funds-flow 
(I am involved with Fintel)

Comment: Maybe you should disclose your affiliation to fintel.io in your answer..?

Answer (score 0):

Folks are definitely using 13F data for making trading strategies. I [grab it from here](https://sites.google.com/view/sec-form-13f-data-sets/) in .xlsx format and just start analyzing it with other macro-economic data.